# ngPattern for validatin a String

Tags: angularjs, regex, ng-pattern

We have a requirement for a string field validation as below:

- It can contain alpha numeric characters and spaces are allowed too.
  But entire string can not be empty spaces alone.
- Lenth is minimun 1 character and maximum legth is 7.
- Case insensitive.

I tried the following Regex but it did not work.

```
/^(?!\s+$)[a-z\d\-_\s]{1,7}+$/i
```

Example Strings that should match: "QWE RTY", "qwe", "13 Z x", "sh qwe1"
Example Strings that shoud not match:

- "qw##@"(includes special characters)
- "        "(spaces)
- "qwerty123"(more than 7 characters)

Comment: can you add few sample input strings that should match and should not match to make it easier to test?

Comment: Use `/^(?!\s+$)[a-z\d\s-]{1,7}$/i`. You basically need to remove `+` after `}` as JS regex does not support possessive quantifiers.